# RecyclerView with fixed row count

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to have a recyclerView with fixed row count not scrollable and every row has a fixed height as well to fill all screen. For example, I had 4 rows so row height should be recyclerView height /4.

Row layout .xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/border"
android:clickable="true"

>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/carte_recto"
    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
    app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>
```

RecyclerView:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:scrollbars="none" />
```

java code :

```
 mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),1, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(getActivity(), onItemClickListener));
    mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(storeAdapter);
    storeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not using a `LinearLayout` with vertical orientation and same weight for every item?

Comment: In case row count changes, one day maybe, it will be easy to add new element to the list than adding new view.

Comment: You can do it programmatically, get height of parent layout where the recyclerview resides and divide that height by 4 which will be height of item of recyclerview. Now set that height to recyclerview item where you are inflating the view.

Comment: ok I will try it. I do that in My adapter class or in my fragment?

Comment: If the row count may change a lot you may have some issues if it becomes so high that the rows have a very little height

Comment: I used a LinearLayout like you said and I got what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Grid Layout manager with a span of 4.

```
layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), **4**, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Adapter

```
 @Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 4;
}
```

by returning a specific number, you can fix the number of iterations.

If you want to make it not scrollable, then `return 1` in `getCount()`and define 4 items in your `MyRow.xml` and use `weight_sum`.